# Generate my own X-axis values / Replace X-axis with own values

Tags: gnuplot

I have a set of 500 data points, but I wish to label the X axis from 1 to 100, as this is 500 data points from a 100 ns timeframe.

Here is my gnuplot input file (stripped of all decoration):

```
set yrange [0:]
plot "PvP_all.agr" using 1:2 title '' with lines lw 1
```

Here's the top 15 lines from PvP_all.agr:

```
@with g0
@  xaxis label "Frame"
@  yaxis label ""
@  legend 0.2, 0.995
@  legend char size 0.60
@  s0 legend "PvP_all"
@target G0.S0
@type xy
1.000       1.4106
2.000       2.3436
3.000       1.8033
4.000       1.9517
5.000       1.9163
6.000       1.7445
7.000       1.8902
```

The columns continue to 500.000

[This is an imgur hosted image of the resulting plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaPju.png)

What I want instead is the exact same data, but the X axis should be 1 to 100 with tics every 25, instead of 1 to 500. How can I do that? Post editing won't work, as I have a lot of them to make.

Note: Original edited as I was linking to an r question and mistakenly trying to use r commands in gnuplot.

Comment: Indeed, the linked answer has nothing to do with gnuplot, so of course you won't find those commands. If you could explain better what you actually want, and how your data looks like, we can probably help you.

Comment: Thanks @Christoph I've edited the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use the line number to generate such data. It can be referenced in the "using" specifier as (pseudo)column zero, e.g.

```
t(n) = 0.2 * n
plot dataf using (t($0)):2 w l
```

("line number" means number of lines with valid data. Comments, blanks are not counted.)

As you saved the line number in the first column, you can of course also use that instead.

The number of consecutive datablocks (separated by single blank lines) and datasets (separated by double blank lines, see "help index") can be referenced as columns number "-1" and "-2", btw. See "help pseudocolumn".

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
set xtics 25
plot "PvP_all.agr" using ($1/5):2 title '' with lines lw 1
```